# Bitmap image sent through bundle is random in the next activity

Tags: android, bitmap, bundle

I have a First `Activity` with a `recyclerview` containing 3 elements which are sent through bundle in the next `Activity`. The 2 text elements are easy to get.

However, when I am putting an `image` through converting the bitmap, it displays a random image from the previous activity's list of items.

Here is my `recyclerview` `adapter` code of the first activity:

```
public class FurnitureAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FurnitureAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //All methods in this adapter are required for a bare minimum recyclerview adapter
    private ArrayList<ItemsModel> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable;

    // Constructor of the class
    public FurnitureAdapter(ArrayList<ItemsModel> itemList, Context context) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // get the size of the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList == null ? 0 : itemList.size();
    }

    // specify the row layout file and click for each row
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_recycler_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder myViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    // load data in each row element
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
        TextView title = holder.title;
        TextView description = holder.description;
        title.setText(itemList.get(listPosition).getTitle());
        description.setText(itemList.get(listPosition).getDescription());
        imageView.setImageDrawable(itemList.get(listPosition).getImage());
        //TODO: Use this line to set drawable in a variable
        bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) itemList.get(listPosition).getImage();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView title, description;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image_view);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemDescriptionsActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("item_title", title.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("item_description", description.getText().toString());

            //Lines added to get BitmapDrawable and then get bitmap from bitmapDrawable
            bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) itemList.get(listPosition).getImage();
            bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            i.putExtra("picture", bytes);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    } }
```

And here's my next receiving bundle activity code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    itemTitle.setText(bundle.getString("item_title"));
    itemDescription.setText(bundle.getString("item_description"));
    //Get Image and conversion
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("picture");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    itemImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you dealing with bitmaps and complicating your data object? Why not just use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) or any image library which [caches](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) and helps [reuse](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/resourcereuse.html) of image resources? And if you're storing the images or bundling them with your app as a resource, then just fetch it that way again in the next activity by just passing some image name or id etc?

Comment: I agree with Naseem, a large bitmap could make your app crash because Bundle has a memory limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data another activity using your list data. No need to         "bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) itemList.get(listPosition).getImage();"
assign drawable every time in the variable. It holds always the last position drawable that's why you are always getting random data in another activity. Note: Check position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION because an item was deleted, but the user clicked it before the UI removed it

```
    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int listPosition = getAdapterPosition(); // gets item position
              if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemDescriptionsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("item_title", itemList.get(listPosition).getTitle());
                bundle.putString("item_description", 
                itemList.get(listPosition).getDescription());

            bitmap =(BitmapDrawable)itemList.get(listPosition).getImage();
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new 
                ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, 
                byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                i.putExtra("picture", bytes);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }}
```

Comment: Logically, your code works. However, I'm getting an error at the line "bitmap =(BitmapDrawable)itemList.get(listPosition).getImage();" saying Incompatible types required Bitmap but found BitmapDrawable. I'm trying to compress a bitmap where it getting a bitmapDrawable

Comment: Nevermind, it's done, I just added another line.. (edited in quesition code).